# 'configure: error: cannot determine current directory' after running 'stack setup' on nixos

Tags: haskell-stack, nixos

I try to run `stack setup` on nixos and get the following error.

```
$ stack setup
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Already downloaded.                
Running /home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/ghc-8.0.2/configure --prefix=/home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/ in directory /home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/ghc-8.0.2/ exited with ExitFailure 1

checking for path to top of build tree...
/home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/ghc-8.0.2/configure: utils/ghc-pwd/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-pwd-bindist: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
configure: error: cannot determine current directory


Error: Error encountered while configuring GHC with
         /home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/ghc-8.0.2/configure --prefix=/home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/
         run in /home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/ghc-8.0.2/

The following directories may now contain files, but won't be used by stack:
  - /home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/
  - /home/matthew/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/

Configuring GHC ...
```

It seems that the error is due to the fact that nixos does not have the conventional `/bin/bash` location (bash is instead located at `/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash` for my nixos setup).

A similar error was raised [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1694) -- That issue was apparently resolved by updating stack, but I already have stack's most recent version so my issue must be different.

Should I run `$ ln -s /run/current-system/sw/bin/bash /bin/bash`, creating a symbolic link at the bash path stack seems to expect? Or is there perhaps some way of informing stack of my system's bash location?

In addition to finding a solution that can simply work, I am also wondering whether there a particular solution that is consistent with the nixos philosophy of immutability, reproducability, etc.

Comment: have you try `stack --nix setup`?, creating `/bin/bash` is obviously not nix's way.

Comment: Also, there is [Haskell guilde](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/languages-frameworks/haskell.md)